# Callback with Datatable.ajax.reload

Tags: jquery, datatables

Hi I am trying to execute a statement after `datable_name.ajax.reload(null, false);`
Below is mycode:

```
datable_name.ajax.reload(null, false);
$('#div_id').removeClass().addClass("text-green").html("Message").fadeIn();
```

My code is working, but the second line is not waiting for the complete execution of data table reload.
I want second line should execute only after complete the execution of first line.

How I can do that. is there any way I can user call back in reload.?

I am using `DataTables 1.10.11`

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
datable_name.ajax.reload(function() {
    $('#div_id').removeClass().addClass("text-green").html("Message").fadeIn();
},false);
```